# Typing in text into a field with WWW::Firefox::Mechanize

Tags: perl, www-mechanize-firefox

I am using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` to do some automation task on a website.

Now I am facing the problem that I need to simulate the entering of characters into an `<input type="text">` field. This is because the typing causes the site to do some AJAX calls to the webserver.

So, is there a way to use W::M::F to have it *enter* or *type* characters.

Comment: Is it using the `onKey*` events?

Comment: It it an option for you to change to Selenium and [Selenium-Remote-Driver](https://metacpan.org/release/Selenium-Remote-Driver)?

Comment: @simbaque: I honestly don't know and I wouldn't know to figure out if it does.

Comment: @Selenium-Remote-Driver I can't tell because most part of the automtion work well and I am not sure if I want to go to the pain to make them work again with another technology.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @StevieD yes, I managed to find a way around with `Win32::GuiTest`. I use this module to simulate the necessary key strokes with `SendKeys`.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger hmm, OK, I'm on a Linux box. That won't work for me. I'll hunt around to see if there might be an equivalent.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger found this: http://search.cpan.org/~ctrondlp/X11-GUITest-0.28/GUITest.pm

I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way around with `Win32::GuiTest`. I use this module to simulate the necessary key strokes with `SendKeys`.
                    – René Nyffenegger